# Monitor all login attempts

Tags: ssh, security, logs, login

Few weeks ago I thought it would be a good idea to write a script to send me an email whenever some user logs in into my server.

So I came with a perfectly working script `notifyLogin.sh`, then I decided to call it from each user's  `.bash_login` script.

But I discovered that someone could log in in my server using `ssh` `-t` switch to select an available shell. For example:

```
ssh user@myserver -t sh
```

This way, `.bash_login` does not execute, neither does `/etc/profile`.

Is there any way to call `notifyLogin.sh` independent of shell type at log in? (It should always work)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, let `rsyslog` do everything for you.  It has the ability to send emails when patterns are matched in syslog messages before they ever hit a file.

Set your email address and SMTP server in the following and put it in your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` or drop it in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` and **restart rsyslog**

```
$ModLoad ommail
$ActionMailSMTPServer localhost
$ActionMailFrom rsyslog@whatever.com
$ActionMailTo you@youremail.com
$template mailSubject,"Login Alert on %hostname%"
$template mailBody,"\n\n%msg%"
$ActionMailSubject mailSubject
$ActionExecOnlyOnceEveryInterval 1
# the if ... then ... mailBody mus be on one line!
if $msg contains 'session opened for user' then :ommail:;mailBody
```

This will fire off an email when `rsyslog` matches the string `session opened for user` in 
a message.

You can look in `/var/log/auth.log` for messages from `sshd` to see what else you can use as patterns.

Source: [rsyslog ommail](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ommail.html)

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not rely on user's .profile because they can change it. If it's really **your** server, you could:

- test for entries in auth.log, utmp or so periodically (or triggered by inotify)
- write a wrapper for `/bin/login`, that does your things and then executes the real `/bin/login`. (I am not quite sure if e.g. ssh executes `/bin/login`, but I expect so.) But I can't recommend that - it's too dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

Keep track of attempts to your system

```
cat /var/log/auth.log grep sshd.\*Failed
```

this can grep failed attempts, also timestamps is available so you can tune it to your script,
also maybe with

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

you can trace input all the time and then do some regexp.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question about sending an email when someone logs in

Comment: you can use the this command to get specific day ssh access  
`sudo cat /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd | grep 'Oct 10'`

Answer (score 2):

I like @creek's solution from above, but with one small change:

```
if $msg contains 'session opened for user' then :ommail:;mailBody`
```

to

```
if $msg contains 'sshd:session' then :ommail:;mailBody`
```

If you simply use "session opened for user" you will get a message every time your cronjobs fire.  For me at least, I just want to monitor SSH.  You could adjust the conditional above to suit any other need.

Answer (score 2):

Following @Creek answer; With rsyslog, to match multiple users (not the best implementation and can be probably replaced with regex, but it works)

```
$ModLoad ommail
$ActionMailSMTPServer localhost
$ActionMailFrom source@mail.com
$ActionMailTo target@mail.com
$template mailSubject,"Login alert on %hostname%"
# mailBody must be on one line!
$template mailBody,"\n\n%msg%"
$ActionMailSubject mailSubject
$ActionExecOnlyOnceEveryInterval 1

if $msg contains 'session opened for' then {
        if $msg contains 'USER1' then :ommail:;mailBody

        # Repetition required (did not investigate why)
        $ActionMailSMTPServer localhost
        $ActionMailFrom source@mail.com
        $ActionMailTo target@mail.com
        $template mailSubject,"Login alert on %hostname%"
        $template mailBody,"\n\n%msg%"
        $ActionMailSubject mailSubject
        $ActionExecOnlyOnceEveryInterval 1

        if $msg contains 'USER2' then :ommail:;mailBody
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but I wrote something to monitor successful and failed ssh connections/attempts. As well as banned IPs if you're using sshguard. I wrote it in Python and in Ruby. It will email you when someone successfully connects via ssh, when someone gets the ssh password wrong or when someone is banned due to to many failed attempts. Hopefully this will help someone in the future who searches for this issue and finds my code!

Python Implementation:

```
https://github.com/amboxer21/SSHMonitorPy
```

Ruby implementation:

```
https://github.com/amboxer21/SSHMonitor
```

For the python script, I wrote a bash script to monitor the process. It checks if it's running every minute via root cron task. If it is not running, it starts another process.

Bash script:

**/home/anthony/.ssh/is_sshm_running.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ `ps aux | egrep --color -i "root.*[0-9]*:[0-9]* sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/SSHMonitor.py" | wc -l` < 1 ]]; then
  sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/SSHMonitor.py -e "example@gmail.com" -p "password" &
fi

if [[ `ps aux | egrep --color -i "root.*[0-9]*:[0-9]* sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/SSHMonitor.py" | wc -l` > 1 ]]; then
  sudo kill -9 `ps aux | egrep --color -i "root.*[0-9]*:[0-9]* sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/SSHMonitor.py" | awk '{print $2}'`;
fi
```

Which is called by this **root** cron task every minute:

```
[anthony@ghost ImageCapturePy]$ sudo crontab -l
[sudo] password for anthony: 
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/anthony/.ssh/is_sshm_running.sh
```

Comment: If the exact same answer works for different questions, then it is likely the questions are duplicates. In that case you should flag the duplicate question accordingly.